# How can I interrupt an executable invoked inside a script without interrupting the script itself?

Tags: powershell

Let's say you have the following script saved in a file `outermost.ps1`:

```
powershell.exe -Command "while ( 1 -eq 1 ) {} "
echo "Done"
```

When running `outermost.ps1` you can only abort this by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and no output will be written to console. How can I modify it so that the outermost script continues and executes `echo "Done"` when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is pressed?

This is a simplified version of a real-life scenario where the inner script is actually an executable which only is stoppable by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

**Edit:** The script could also be:

```
everlooping.exe
echo "Done"
```

but I wanted to provide an example everyone could copy-paste into an editor if they wanted to "try at home".

Comment: whats the point in having "powershell.exe -Command " in a powershell script?

Comment: See my comment in paranthesis. The actual `outermost.ps1`looks more like Line 1:  somestupid.exe, Line 2: Echo "done"

Comment: so no "powershell.exe -Command " after all?

Comment: So your question is really: "How can I interrupt an executable invoked inside a powershell script?"

Comment: Yes, sorry didn't know how to phrase it properly

Comment: for a start: Get-Help Start-Process -full

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to this is:

```
    Start-Process -Wait "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "while ( 1 -eq 1 ) {}"
    echo "Done"
```

This will spawn a second window unlinke [ansgar-wiechers solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611807/507339), but solves my problem with the least amount of code.

Thanks to Jaqueline Vanek for the tip

Answer (score 4):

Start your infinite command/statement as a [job](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288.aspx), make your PowerShell script process <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> as regular input (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10180160/1630171)), and stop the job when that input is received:

```
[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $true

$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  powershell.exe -Command "while ( 1 -eq 1 ) {} "
}

while ($true) {
  if ([Console]::KeyAvailable) {
    $key = [Console]::ReadKey($true)
    if (($key.Modifiers -band [ConsoleModifiers]::Control) -and $key.Key -eq 'c') {
      $job.StopJob()
      break
    }
  }
  Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}

Receive-Job -Id $job.Id
Remove-Job -Id $job.Id

echo "Done"
```

If you need to retrieve output from the job while it's running, you can do so like this in an `else` branch to the outer `if` statement:

```
if ($job.HasMoreData) { Receive-Job -Id $job.Id }
```