# How can I make a PowerShell child process close cleanly?

Tags: .net, windows, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that creates child processes. I would like to tell the child processes that they should close cleanly. By close cleanly, I mean that they should finish the work that they are currently doing and then exit.

I can send the process a kill() command, but that immediately terminates the process. An ugly method would be to have the parent write to a file and have the child monitor that file. I'm looking for something more elegant like passing a signal or event.

Comment: Why don't the child processes close by themselves when they're finished?

Comment: Are the child processes your own PowerShell scripts? You can, in general, intercept SIGINT (Ctrl-C) and do something to shutdown cleanly. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179032/trapping-signals-in-powershell for using Try/Finally in PowerShell.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - They are running while($true) loops, so they run forever unless killed or they hit another trigger (related to the ugly method mentioned above.)

Comment: @lit - I checked out that article, but the Finally block doesn't seem to run if I end the process with Kill() or the Stop-Process cmdlet.

Comment: If you want processes to terminate cleanly after they finished their task: don't have them run an infinite loop.

Comment: "They are running while($true) loops" - why?

Comment: I am not going to change the while($true) loops. That's code that I do not manage.

Comment: Then you don't have a clean way of terminating the processes. Plain and simple.